# Unable to install tensorflow_io on M1 Mac?

Tags: macos, tensorflow, tensorflow-io

Am currently following a tutorial. Was able to do pip install tensorflow no problem, however when I do pip install tensorflow-io I get this error: "No matching distribution found for tensorflow-io". pip install tensorflow_io doesn't work as well and gives the same error.

Answer (score -1):

After having checked on different sources, it seems to be a recurring issue with Apple M1.
Here is the reference: [GitHub](https://github.com/tensorflow/io/issues/1625)

Comment: Yes I previously saw that thread. Are we just out of luck then, can't do specific types of work because we run macOS?

Comment: Seems to be. :-/
However, I could use it perfectly on Google Colab